# insert or update the date value as sysdate via stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure:

```
create proc proc_ins_upd_exp
    @id             int = 0,
    @itemname       nvarchar(200),
    @price          decimal,
    @dateofbilling  date
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if (@id = 0)
       insert into exp_tbl (itemname, price, dateofbilling) 
       values (@itemname, @price, @dateofbilling)
    else
       update exp_tbl
       set itemname = isnull (@itemname, itemname),
           price = isnull (@price, price),
           dateofbilling = isnull (@dateofbilling , dateofbilling)
       where id = @id

   set nocount off;
end;
```

In the table `exp_tbl`, the column `dateofbilling` is of datatype `date`.

How can I insert the value of `dateofbilling` as getdate via the stored procedure or update the value of `dateofbilling` with sysdate when this value is NULL?

When I try to execute the stored procedure, I get the error.

```
execute proc_ins_upd_exp 
     @itemname = 'test', @price = 100, @dateofbilling = getdate()
```

Comment: Where's the error ??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a literal value, or a variable, and nothing else to an execute...
In general (with few exceptions) you cannot have any form of complex expression or function invocation

```
Declare @currentDate date = getdate()
execute proc_ins_upd_exp @itemname = 'test', @price = 100, @dateofbilling = @currentDate
```

Comment: declare @curentdate date = getdate()

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER Procedure proc_ins_upd_exp
    @id             int = 0,
    @itemname       nvarchar(200),
    @price          decimal,
    @dateofbilling  date = null
AS
IF @dateofbilling is null
SET @dateofbilling = getdate()
```